# Get a padding/margin on top iOS Webview

Tags: ios, swift, padding

I had a problem. I want a padding or margin on top above the webview.
This is a picture of the problem:

[image]

Who can help me with this problem?

Comment: if you needs maintain the status bar, you can add `20px of top space`. If not just hide the status bar

Comment: Are you making a native app or hybrid app like phonegap ?

Comment: @jose920405 I want to show the status bar. But how do I give 20px of top space?

Comment: @NiravGadhiya a native app with Swift and xCode and I load a webview in the app.

Comment: select your webview in your storyboard and drag and drop to father view. The constraint list should be displayed. Select `Top space to container`. Verify that the space is 20 px.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Way 1 :** Select ViewController in Storybord and Deselect automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets.

[image]

**Way 2 :** Write in View Controller

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO ;
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me...

UPDATE:
It works! Thank you! I must delete also some constraints.

Comment: Sorry! It works! I did something wrong the first time.